# Windows Server 2008 r2 remote access

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I have recently come into a company running Windows Server 2008 R2. The remote access has been switched off and users in another building are unable to login correctly and new users cannot log on.

I have tried myself and the message says that there is no logon server available.

Please can anyone advise how to enable to remote access again

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support. Try the DBA site. But this is probably NOT an mssql problem,and your domain controller has barfed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is listed on this page

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393699(v=ws.10).aspx